# Extend a class from another module in sass

Tags: css, sass

I have a Sass module containing a useful class that I both want to use as it is in my HTML and extend in my Sass.

/src/styles/components/grid.scss

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;

  &__1-col {
    @extend .grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

/src/styles/components/section.scss

```css
@use './grid.scss' as *;

.section {
  @extend .grid;
  min-height: 100lvh;

  &__1-col {
    @extend .grid__1-col;
    @extend .section;
    grid-template-areas: "title";
  }
}
```

In section.scss I want to extend my `.grid` class with the extra functionality and also extend the composite `.grid__1-col` class in the `.section__1-col` class.

This gets the following error:

```
 [vite] Internal server error: [sass] The target selector was not found.
 Use "@extend .grid !optional" to avoid this error.
   ╷
 5 │   @extend .grid;
   │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
 src/styles/components/section.scss 5:3  root stylesheet
```

Note: this error is occurring in the section.scss so the `@extend .grid;` in grid.scss seems fine.

A simple fix for this is to use `@import` which totally still works but as this has been [deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/) I'd like to get this right.

I have tried the following

```css
@use './grid.scss';
```

```css
@use 'grid';
```

```css
@use 'grid' as grid;
...
@extend grid.grid;
```

Note: ^ this gives the following error

```
[vite] Internal server error: [sass] compound selectors may no longer be extended.
Consider `@extend grid, .grid` instead.
See https://sass-lang.com/d/extend-compound for details.
```

using a placeholder in grid.scss

```css
%grid {
  display: grid;
}

// in .section.scss
.grid {
  @extend %grid;
}
```

but same problem